# How to use BarChartRodData of fl_chart

Tags: flutter

I want to make an app and I need to use `fl_chart`.
The question is: What do I do to make a space for each element evenly.

How can I do it like this screenshot?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Remove the property [`alignment`](https://github.com/imaNNeoFighT/fl_chart/blob/master/repo_files/documentations/bar_chart.md#barchartalignment) from the [`BarChartData`](https://github.com/imaNNeoFighT/fl_chart/blob/master/repo_files/documentations/bar_chart.md#barchartdata) (Most probably it's set to `center`). It's going to use the `spaceBetween` instead as default.

It's going to be like the following:

```dart
BarChart(
  BarChartData(
    // Remove the `alignment` or change it to `spaceBetween`
    alignment: BarChartAlignment.spaceBetween,
    ...
  ),
  ...
),
```

Also, if not already wrap `BarChart` with a [`Expanded`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) widget.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you could set up "barsSpace" in the parameter of "BarChartGroupData".

[Example from fl_chart](https://github.com/imaNNeoFighT/fl_chart/blob/master/example/lib/bar_chart/samples/bar_chart_sample4.dart)

##### BarChartGroupData

| PropName | Description | default value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | x position of the group on horizontal axis | null |
| barRods | list of BarChartRodData that are a bar line | [] |
| barsSpace | the space between barRods of the group | 2 |
| showingTooltipIndicators | indexes of barRods to show the tooltip on top of them | [] |